# jQuery pass data-attribute to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use my HTML element to pass a data-attribute to jQuery but I can't seem to use that data-attribute as an option in the function:

Instead of

```
    var options1 = {
        series: [60, 10, 30],
```

I am trying to use

```
    <div id="evaluation" class="donut" data-series="60,10,30">

    autoValues = $('#evaluation').attr('data-series');
    const evaluation = [autoValues];

    var options1 = {
        series: evaluation,
        ...
</script>
```

This is returning a NaN error.

Comment: Looks like after you edited, it returns the correct records? Or you want the series data to be an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute value is a string. You need to split the string and parse them to create a list of integers.

You can also use the `.data()` jQuery method to access `data` attributes.

```js
autoValues = $('#evaluation').data('series');
const evaluation = autoValues.split(',').map(Number);
var options1 = {
  series: evaluation,
};

console.log(options1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="evaluation" class="donut" data-series="60,10,30">
```

Answer (score 1):

Data attributes are strings so you'd have to convert that string to numbers.
jQuery's `.data()` can parse your data attributes to data types if you specify them as json

```js
 
 const evaluation = $('#evaluation').data('series');

 var options1 = {
     series: evaluation,
 }
 console.log(options1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="evaluation" class="donut" data-series="[60,10,30]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes are essentially just strings. As such, `evaluation = [autoValues]` is effectively the same as `evaluation = ["60,10,30"]`.

**However**, you may want to store JSON in your data attributes, because *jQuery will automatically try to `JSON.parse` them for you* if you use the `data()` function, i.e. `$('#evaluation').data('series')`.

```js
const options = {
  series: $('#evaluation').data('series')
};
console.log(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="evaluation" class="donut" data-series="[60,10,30]">
```

With this approach, you could even store the entire options object in a single data attribute:

```js
const options = $('#evaluation').data('options');
console.log(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="evaluation" class="donut" data-options='{"series": [60,10,30]}'>
```